# MobileFirst cannot find libauthjni.so while connecting with HTTPS, works with HTTP

Tags: cordova, android-studio, https, ibm-mobilefirst

`mfp -v 7.1.0.00.20160206-1603`
`wladm -version 7.1.0.00.20150807-0630`
The project type is `mfp cordova ...`
Building with Android Studio, gradle scripts are auto generated by `mfp cordova` so it must be supported.

When app connects to production with Https, I get this error. (tested on several devices)
`couldn't find "libauthjni.so"`

When I connect to developer server with Http - everything is ok.
Have you seen this before?

Log
`wlclient init success
D/NONE: establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
D/NONE: Request [/apps/services/api/com_myapp/android/init]
D/NONE: establishSSLClientAuth
E/com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler: Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java:470 :: Uncaught Exception

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libauthjni.so"

E/NONE: Request timeout for [/apps/services/api/com_myapp/android/init]`

Comment: Have you tried removing the Android environment, adding it again and then testing?

Also, is your studio version the same as the server version? What is the exact studio version?

Comment: Im not using mfp studio or eclipse. The project type is mfp cordova... So I use Android studio to build apk's. Gradle build script is auto generated by mfp cordova

Comment: Can you see to change the port number for https

Comment: "libauthjni.so" is used in case of application authenticity. Are you using application authenticity test in your application?

Can you verify if the folders "armeabi, armeabi-v7a, mips, and x86" have the file?

Comment: Yes. libauthjni.so exists in these folders. And authenticity is On by default for mobile application (mobile-security-test). But maybe it is not being build into application. How can I check if it is included in build. When I connect to developer server, autenticity is not being checked. And this problem does not arise.

Comment: I actually noticed now that my apk has smaller size that before. It maybe because of library is not included in build. How can I ensure? How to check?

Comment: .apk is a zip file. Rename the file extension and extract it.

Comment: it's not there. The build does not include it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. With default Gradle script, the native libraries are not being built into apk.
There are two solutions on StackOverflow
 - `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = ["libs"]` which doesn't works for me now.
 - change path `libs/**/*.so` to `src/main/jniLibs/**/*.so`
Library was included, and application was able to connect and pass autenticity test.
Thanks to `Vivin K` and `Idan Adar`, I solved this quite fast.